# Powershell: Does System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter usange in powershell need some ADO.Net installation?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, scripting, powershell, excel

In PowerShell, goal is to query some data from Sql Server and put that into a preformatted Excel file. Towards that, the following PowerShell script snippet, throws an error saying "assemblies are missing".

From what I could gather online, `SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter` is part of `ADO.Net`, which does not require including any assemblies (**as it is always present in the OS .Net framework installation**). Is this correct? How do I rectify this?

```
...
... other connection code
...
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $ActiveTransactions_Count_Query;

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;

$DataSet_ActiveTransaction = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet_ActiveTransaction);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet_ActiveTransaction.Tables[0];
$DataSetTable
```

Error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Sql.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter]: make sure
the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At M:\Build.ps1:21 char:25 + $SqlAdapter = New-Object <<<< 
Sql.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object],
    PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data
```

Yes it's part of the OS, and no this is not normally required, but there must be some issue from the combination of your OS version + PowerShell version + SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: If it helps,Windows Server 2008 R2 + Sql 2008 R2 + PowerShell Version 2